# Why is my React DOM not reloading on navigating from within my website unlike it does while reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-state

So,using Socket Io to make a real time bi way communication app. When receiver reloads his inbox page ,he gets the new message from sender,which updates the state variable containing messages and displays the message in real time on the screen.But when receiver navigates to inbox page from a different page by clicking on MessageIcon and then tries receiving messages ,the new message although appears on the console but the state containing the messages does not get updated .

```
 const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
 const socket = useRef()
//to receive the incoming message from sender
 const [incoming, setIncoming] = useState(null)
 useEffect(() => {
        socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8900")
//getting new message from socket io backend 
        socket.current.on("getMessage", data => {
            //updating the incoming state variable with the new message
             setIncoming({
                receiverId: data.receiverId,
                senderId: data.senderId,
                type: data.type,
                text: data.text,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                conversationId: data.conversationId
            })
            //console.log(data)
        })
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
//updating the message array with the new message to display the upcoming message on the screen
        incoming && setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incoming])

    }, [incoming])//condition to run useEffect as soon as incoming is populated
```

I have asked a friend of mine,he told me it could be a problem with DOM not reloading .